# Xcode: Implicit declaration of function invalid trouble

Tags: c, xcode, function, declaration, implicit

When I use:

```
delay(XXX);
```

and/or

```
modulo(XXX);
```

I get an error saying implicit declaration of function 'delay' or 'modulo' is invalid in C99.

I read that I need to declare it before I call it, so I tried many variations of:

```
void delay(int);
```

and

```
void modulo(int);
```

at the top of the program. It then doesn't build or still has the error..

This program is very very simple and was wondering if someone could tell me or teach me how to get it to work. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    float a, b;
    float s, d, p, q;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");

    scanf("%f", &a);

    printf("\nPlease enter another number: ");

    scanf("%f", &b);

    /* Calculate Sum, Difference, Product and Quotient */
    s = (a + b);
    d = modulo(a - b);     // error occurs here
    p = (a * b);
    q = (a / b);

    printf("\nSum: %.2f\nDifference: %.2f\nProduct: %.2f\nQuotient: %.2f", s, d, p, q);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: There isn't any standard function named `modulo` or `delay`. FYI, `%` is the modulus operator and you can use `sleep` instead of `delay`(after including `Windows.h`)

Comment: Just curious: What do you expect `modulo` to do in this code?

Comment: I would like the difference to always be a positive value. And thanks, sleep worked but by including unistd.h

Comment: Ok i'm sorted, was looking for abs.